# Cannot use/pass shell variables using jq on command line

Tags: environment-variables, key, command-line-arguments, jq

I am fairly new to jq and I am using this tutorial to add a new Org to a hyperledger fabric network.

There is extensive use of jq throughout the tutorial, especially modifying json files.

The tutorial uses an example Org name but I am trying to make the org name dynamic. Everything works out well except when I try to pass variables to jq.

Here are the jq commands and their outputs.

jq version: 1.5.1

$ export MSPID=Org4MSP
$ echo $MSPID
Org4MSP

Trying to pass the variable using env.

Keyword: env.MSPID

$ jq -s '.[0] * {"channel_group":{"groups":{"Application":{"groups": {"env.MSPID":.[1]}}}}}' config.json org4.json

*Output snippet: Instead of printing Org4MSP, it prints the literal string env.MSPID*

```
      "env.MSPID": {
        "groups": {},
        "mod_policy": "Admins",
        "policies": {
          "Admins": {
            "mod_policy": "Admins",
            "policy": {
              "type": 1,
              "value": {
                "identities": [
                  {
```

Trying to pass the variable using --arg option

Keyword: "$MSP"

jq --arg MSP "$MSPID" -s '.[0] * {"channel_group":{"groups":{"Application":{"groups": {"$MSP":.[1]}}}}}' config.json org4.json

*Output snippet: Instead of printing Org4MSP, it prints the literal string $MSP*

```
      "$MSP": {
        "groups": {},
        "mod_policy": "Admins",
        "policies": {
          "Admins": {
            "mod_policy": "Admins",
            "policy": {
              "type": 1,
              "value": {
                "identities": [
                  {
```

Trying to pass a variable using --arg option and without using double quotes:

keyword: $MSP

$ jq --arg MSP "$MSPID" -s '.[0] * {"channel_group":{"groups":{"Application":{"groups": {$MSP:.[1]}}}}}' config.json org4.json

jq: error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '}' (Unix shell quoting issues?) at , line 1:

.[0] * {"channel_group":{"groups":{"Application":{"groups": {$MSP:.[1]}}}}}

jq: 1 compile error

Trying to pass variable using env. and without double quotes:

keyword: env.MSPID

$ jq -s '.[0] * {"channel_group":{"groups":{"Application":{"groups": {env.MSPID:.[1]}}}}}' config.json org4.json

jq: error: syntax error, unexpected FIELD, expecting '}' (Unix shell quoting issues?) at , line 1:

.[0] * {"channel_group":{"groups":{"Application":{"groups": {env.MSPID:.[1]}}}}}

jq: 1 compile error

I apologize if this seems to be a trivial question but I have searched online and in docs and do not understand why the JSON key will not convert to the shell variable's value.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Environment variables

In your sub-expression:

```
{"env.MSPID":.[1]}
```

you have quoted `env.MSPID` thereby making it a literal string.  Since you want to invoke the `env` function, you should instead write:

```
{ (env.MSPID):.[1]}
```

The parentheses are needed to ensure that jq will evaluate the parenthesized expression properly.

### {$MSP:.[1]}

As noted above, when an expression must be evaluated to determine the string-value of a key, the expression must be parenthesized, e.g.

```
 {($MSP):.[1]}
```

Comment: Excellent. Thank you so much!